# API search page size limit mismatch

Tags: bug, status-completed, api

The [1.1 API help text for search](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/search) says that the `pagesize` parameter can go up to 100. Indeed, passing a value up to 100 returns some results, while passing `pagesize=101` yields an HTTP 400 status (`Bad Request`). However, only up to 30 results are actually returned per page even if `pagesize=100` (e.g. http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/search?tagged=c&pagesize=100).

Comment: I can reproduce this. Although the `pagesize` property is set to 100, only 30 results are returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed.

There was a bug with paging results coming from Lucene (which serves most, but not all, `/search` requests at this time).

Comment: Weirdly, http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/search?tagged=c&pagesize=100 returns only 99 questions. Going down, http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/search?tagged=c&pagesize=10 returns only the same 9 questions as http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/search?tagged=c&pagesize=9 . Is this by design (I can think of legitimate reasons such as a deleted question)? This makes me wonder [how to get all the results of a search](http://stackapps.com/questions/2147/prefered-way-to-retrieve-all-search-results).