# Where do I get UUID for fetching user's associations?

Tags: support, associated

Yesterday (09/17/2011) I could go to my stackexchange site's profile page and grab UUID from the url:

[image]

I could use this UUID to fetch [user's associations](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/stackauth-methods/user-associations) with stack exchange network. Now said URL redirects to another page where the actual ID is (presumably) auto incremental integer which used in latter URL returns no associations. Is that UUID is being forbidden public access? What id should I use to get user's associations?

Comment: According to [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/2588/draft-specification-for-api-v2-0) page, the entire network is switching from association GUIDs to something called an account ID. This is likely causing the problem.

Comment: Indeed. I reread the 2.0 draft and it seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the user's association id through the `/users/{ids}` route

Eg:

http://api.stackapps.com/1.1/users/1608

(see `association_id`)

Comment: This is no good as it's just one extra, site-dependent(!!!) step to fetch needed `association_id`. Won't there be any other place where I can fetch all user's associations without asking what's their id on specific site?

Comment: What are you trying to do then? Get every single user's association Id?

Comment: I'm trying to fetch all associations (which return site's name too) by knowing association_id instantly.

Comment: So where are you planning on getting the association_id from in the first place?  You're meant to get the association_id from the route in my post, put that in the stackauth route and get all the associations.

Comment: Previously association_id was in the stack exchange user's profile url (as shown in the screenshot).

Comment: Well getting the association Id from anywhere but the API is a bit of a fluke. In 2.0 the association id will become numerical like it is on stack exchange. On normal site you can use JavaScript to get the association I'd of the currently logged in user but it doesnt seem to work on stackexchange.com

Comment: If you say exactly what you're trying to do it may be possible to help you more.