# OBSOLETE - How to get the actual “body” of a question or answer?

Tags: support, obsolete

How do I actually get the body (i.e. the textual content) of any say question or answer.

For example, for question (id= 7406104), I call:

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions/7406104

But in the response, I can only see the title. How can I get the actual question details:

```
{
 "total": 1,
 "page": 1,
 "pagesize": 30,
 "questions": [
  {
   "tags": [
    "java"
   ],
   "answer_count": 5,
   "accepted_answer_id": 7406124,
   "favorite_count": 1,
   "question_timeline_url": "/questions/7406104/timeline",
   "question_comments_url": "/questions/7406104/comments",
   "question_answers_url": "/questions/7406104/answers",
   "question_id": 7406104,
   "owner": {
    "user_id": 587196,
    "user_type": "registered",
    "display_name": "Larry",
    "reputation": 197,
    "email_hash": "4758e22c1321eeaa3c712b516669a629"
   },
   "creation_date": 1315935668,
   "last_activity_date": 1315936683,
   "up_vote_count": 0,
   "down_vote_count": 0,
   "view_count": 46,
   "score": 0,
   "community_owned": false,
   "title": "How do I write my own comparison operator in Java?"
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the [API documentation](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/questions-by-ids), you simply need to [pass in the `body=true` parameter](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions/7406104?body-true) to get the body of the question.

In the [upcoming version of the API](https://stackapps.com/questions/2588/draft-specification-for-api-v2-0), you'll be able to use filters to specify what you want returned in advance.