# Register for the Stack Exchange V2.0 API Private Beta

Tags: discussion, api-v2

It's getting to be that time (actually, it's about a month later than I'd hoped but still!), API V2.0 is shaping up and we're spending more and more time on UI polish rather than functionality.

So let's get this beta started.

What I'm looking for right now are people interested in pre-release access to our docs and application registrations.  Once so armed, you'll be able to begin development immediately.

Established Stack Exchange users will be given priority in the unlikely event too many people show interest, and if that isn't a strict enough filter established Stack Apps users will be preferred (if that's still not a good enough filter, I'm pulling names out of a hat).

If you're interested in what's coming in V2.0, take a look at the [draft spec](https://stackapps.com/questions/2588/draft-specification-for-api-v2-0).  There have been a number of changes, but the gist is still correct.

#### By participating in the private beta your feedback will have a greater chance of impacting the final version.

While we believe the API to be essentially complete, there could very well be some oversights or low hanging feature-requests that may get approved in the private beta.  Once we reach *public beta* we will be much more risk averse, preferring to only fix bugs unless the flaw is truly egregious.

#### This will be a true beta, with lots of rough edges.

Don't expect a Google Beta™.  Though we've done some internal consumption, there will almost certainly be some pretty bad bugs discovered during the beta.

Additionally, lots and lots of UI work remains to be done.  Most of this work is user facing, so I don't see a point in delaying the beta while we polish it.

Most significantly, during the private beta we will not be maintaining backwards compatibility between minor revisions.  Notices will be given when we break things (and we will *try* to give advanced warning), but you should be comfortable with your apps being broken.  Consequently, apps developed during the private beta should not be shipped to end users.

## The Private Beta Has Begun, Registration Closed

Comment: *IMMEDIATELY fills in form...*

Comment: Awesome, now I can resume the XMPP chat bridge!!!!

Comment: @Josh: Well... v2.0 is still going to be read-only :) And there is no API for the chat.

Comment: Bah! Booo... Okay. I don't really need beta access then...

Comment: what is a server key (mentioned in the signup form), I can't see any mention of it in the draft spec?

Comment: ugh, damn it I was going to register but none replied...

Comment: @Jonathan - they turned out to not be necessary, I'll throw you an invite later today.